# Issue with sklearn/numpy dependancies

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

So I have got all the latest packages from using

```
conda update --all
```

however when I try to use sklearns affinity propagation, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Clustering.py", line 114, in <module>
    clust = clust_af.fit_predict(credit_clean)
  File "/home/fd-dsmodeltrainer01/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/                                                                             base.py", line 410, in fit_predict
    self.fit(X)
  File "/home/fd-dsmodeltrainer01/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/                                                                             cluster/affinity_propagation_.py", line 308, in fit
    copy=self.copy, verbose=self.verbose, return_n_iter=True)
  File "/home/fd-dsmodeltrainer01/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/                                                                             cluster/affinity_propagation_.py", line 96, in affinity_propagation
    S.flat[::(n_samples + 1)] = preference
  File "/home/fd-dsmodeltrainer01/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sp                                                                             arse/base.py", line 686, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
AttributeError: flat not found
```

It seems that `sklearn` cant find the `.flat` attribute from `numpy`

Any ideas?

Comment: Try reinstalling numpy.

Comment: Already done that